# Check cookie enabled or disabled in an httpModule in the first request

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpmodule

Is there any method to find browser cookie enabled or disabled in an httpModule.

We are using **HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[“Cookie”]** to check whether cookie enabled or disabled.

But in the initial request it is always showing null value in both cases ie if either cookie enabled or disabled.

I am looking for a method to check browser cookie enabled or disabled in the first request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking not for cookies being enabled or disabled but for whether there are some cookies set.

The only way to check if the cookies are enabled is to try to set some cookies, and on the second request from the client to check if they send you these cookies in their request.

This is impossible to check whether the cookies are enabled in the browser on the first request from the client. Anyway, most cases when the cookies won't work is when the browser configured to silently ignore your cookies, and of course you cannot detect whether it is ignoring your cookies or not without trying to set some cookies.